# Make a number 1 if greater than 0

Tags: c, math, optimization

I am trying to optimize some code, that seems simple but is giving me a hard time. **So basically, I am trying to make a number the value 1, if it is greater than 0.** The problem is that I don't want to use **any** comparisons, as they are very expensive and getting a solution without a comparison will save me 40 seconds as it gets called alot. So all I want is bit wise operators, adding, subtracting, dividing and multiplying.

Extra: The number will ever only be 1 or 2.

The type is a **unsigned int**.

Full Algorithm:

```
        DWORD num = (blockNum / 0xAA) * blockStep[0];

        switch (blockNum / 0xAA)
        {
            case 0:
                return num + hashOffset;

            default:

                num += ((blockNum / 0x70E4) + 1) << (BYTE)packageSex;
                switch (blockNum / 0x70E4)
                {
                    case 0:
                        return num + hashOffset;

                    default:
                        return num + (1 << (BYTE)packageSex) + hashOffset;
                }
        }
```

Comment: If the number is 2, it becomes 1.  If it is 1, it remains 1.  What's the difference?

Comment: The type is a unsigned int. Also, how will I get the number to be 1 if it is 2 with only bit wise operators?

Comment: shift.  But I'm not sure how you're to know if you need to shift or not unless you do a comparison.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I am avoiding any comparisons.

Comment: Your requirement is ridiculous. There's no way to tell if a number is greater than zero or not without doing some kind of comparison. The question doesn't even make sense, and simple integer `CMP` operations are not expensive. This is a case of senseless optimization.

Comment: Can you do a bitwise and?  That shouldn't be an expensive op.  `if(var & 2){ var >>= 1; }`  That's really what `if(var == 2){ var = 1; }` will end up being, anyway.

Comment: That is still considered a comparison. I have found a solution.

Comment: What exactly should that function compute? And where does the requestet functionality come into play?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlJ5SuKr_NM

So many people say that it won't be faster, but it is... Am I just doing something stupid?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This code snippet produces the effect you want. I checked the assembly output (MSVC++ 2010) and it's branchless.

```
n = !!n;
```

Comment: very nice, perfect solution for unsigned int.  What happens when you turn on optimizations, I could see where it might get optimized out.  Would volatile help here?

Comment: This is a good solution, but it still does do comparisons. With this said, this is also very slow.

Comment: are you sure, ideally this would be two NOT assembly instructions on a register

Comment: @hetelek: I highly doubt **any** compiler would generate branches for this code.  Just make sure you comment this code heavily to explain its purpose.  Also, I believe `!0` is guaranteed to be `1` on all systems, so this is more widely applicable *(works for more than just values of 1 and 2)*.

Comment: It is true that no compiler will generate branches, but it will do comparisons. If you look at the disassembly in Visual Studio, it shows a compare operation.

Comment: yes, it is actually garantied by the ansi-c standard that the result of logical operations is either 1 for true or 0 for false

Comment: @hetelek: a comparison-operation doesnt hurt you at all! A branch could hurt you because of failed branch-prediction and a possible pipeline-flush, but a comparison is just a single instruction to be executed, and i dont think that, even with inline-assembler, you could get any less than the three instructions Blastfurnace mentioned earlier from his disassembly..

Comment: Weird... The reason I say this, is because it still ended up being very slow... I have edited my post with the full algorithm.

Comment: @Legionair: I retracted the "three instruction" comment after looking more closely at the assembly. There was a `cmp` instruction I missed. Having said that it is branchless and should be fast on a modern processor.

Comment: I haven't looked at the assembly, but I imagine that the compiler decided that doing a `CMP eax, 0` and setting the register to the `NZ` flag would be faster than two `NOT`'s. This is still branchless, so what I said still stands *(it's branches, not `CMP`'s, that can be expensive)*.  [See also](http://www.blueraja.com/blog/285/branchless-conditionals-compiler-optimization-technique).

Comment: With respect, I would suggest that instead of taking the stance "this is incredibly slow" that you should instead take the stance "I am probably doing something stupid" just like the rest of us.

Answer (score 5):

if it is guarantied that it can only be 1 or 2, then this is quite simple:

1: 0001
2: 0010

by applying a rightshift and OR with itself, both masked with 1, it will always be one

lets say the number is stored in val, then

```
val = (val | val>>1) & 1
```

Comment: Got it right after me :) Thanks anyway.

Comment: hey, i was 20 seconds faster ;-)

Comment: This doesn't work.  2 | (2>>1) = 2 | 1 = 3.

Comment: daamn, i shouldnt post at 5:30AM, you are right, i gonna fix it..

Answer (score 1):

```
(num & 1) | ((num & 2) >> 1)
```

Works for what I am trying to do, which is values 1 and 2. It will also work with more values, but that's not my concern.